# Where to store API keys for Vagrant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vagrant

Where is the best place to store API keys (AWS) using Vagrant? They would be available on vagrant ssh

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='string'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .bashrc

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='string'
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='string'
```